# django many to many relationship query reverse

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, relationship

i have a question with django some relationship  where i want to use and i am very confused with that task.

i have two tables one table is `ball` and other `table` is stadium ,in my problem one stadium maybe to have many balls and one ball maybe to have many stadiums.

here my model :

```
class ball(models.Model):
    code_ball=models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    description_ball = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    made_country_ball= models.CharField(max_length=254)
    f_ball= models.CharField(max_length=254)
    rel= models.ManyToManyField(stadium)

class stadium(models.Model):
    code_stadium=models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    description_stadium = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    made_country_stadium= models.CharField(max_length=254)
    andress_stadium= models.CharField(max_length=254)
    team_stadium= models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

my question is how to create query views to show that in html templates?
for example in some html page need to show all details from table `stadium` and all or fist `code_ball` with `description_bal` from table `balls`.

i don't know hot to do that because i don't have foreign key for table `ball` to table `stadium`,with some way i need to reverse relationship to create a new query,any idea how ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the full functionality of the ManyToMany fields you should define a through table [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). This does not change anything but shows you what really happens behind the scenes. So you can then use the Foreignkey relation for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You got to have an associative entity of the two tables.

```
class ball(models.Model):
    code_ball=models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    description_ball = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    made_country_ball= models.CharField(max_length=254)
    f_ball= models.CharField(max_length=254)
    rel= models.ManyToManyField(stadium, through='StadiumBall')

class stadium(models.Model):
    code_stadium=models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    description_stadium = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    made_country_stadium= models.CharField(max_length=254)
    andress_stadium= models.CharField(max_length=254)
    team_stadium= models.CharField(max_length=254)

class StadiumBall(models.Model):
    stadium = models.ForeignKey(stadium, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ball = models.ForeignKey(ball, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[Here is a documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)